# '\0' related issue

Tags: c++, string

Looking at this loop that copies one c-string to another:

```
void strcpyr(char *s, char *t)
{
    while(*s++=*t++)// Why does this work?
        ;
}
```

Why do we not check for the '\0' character in the while loop, like this?

```
while((*s++=*r++)!='\0')..
```

How does the first loop terminate?

Comment: Please read about markdown and how to enter code into your question. Basically, put four spaces before each line of code.

Comment: Tagged homework, might be a bit harsh?

Comment: Public service: Copying strings like this is unsafe (no bounds checking). Any "serious" or "production" code should (in general) be using safer methods. Personally, I think type of code is more trying too hard to be clever as well.

Answer (score 12):

The statement *s++=*t++ not only assigns the next character from t to s but also returns the current value of *t as the result of the expression. The while loop terminates on any false value, including '\0'.

Think of it this way. If you did:

```
char c = *s++ = *t++;
```

in addition to copying a char from *t to *s and incrementing both, it would also set c to the current value of *t.

Answer (score 4):

When we hit the `'\0'` in the string initially pointed to by `t`, the `*s++=*t++`, which does the assignment, also returns the value that's assigned to the position pointed to by `s`, or `'\0'`, which evaluates to `false` and terminates the loop.

In your second example, you explicitly rely on the fact that the assignment returns the assigned character, while the first example implicitly uses this fact (and the fact that the `0` character (also written `'\0'`) is considered to be false, while all other characters evaluate to true, so the expression `c != '\0'` will yield the same result as `c`.

Answer (score 2):

The loop is going to terminate because '\0' is effectively 0, and the what the "while" is evaluating is not a the result of an equality test (==), but the right-value of the assignment expression.

Answer (score 1):

The reason we are not explicitly checking for zero is that in C 0 is false.

Therefore the loop

```
while(*s++=*t++)
;
```

will terminate when the character pointed to by t is 0.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to write this:

```
void strcpyr(char *s, char *t) {
  while (*s++ = *t++);
}
```

The loop terminates when the value pointed to by "t" is zero. For C (and C++) loops and conditionals, any integer that is non-zero is true.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is testing the result of the assignment.
The result of an assignment is the value assigned into the left-hand side of the statement.  On the last iteration, when *t == '\0', the '\0' is assigned into s, which becomes the value the while loop considers before deciding it is time to quit.

Answer (score 0):

In C, a=b is actually an expression which is evaluated as 'b'. It is easier to write:

```
if(a=b) {
 //some block
}
```

then:

```
a=b;
if(a!=0) {
 //some block
}
```

In C language within if, while, for statement the check that is made is: is expression not zero?